Specific regularity in bipartite graphs
Let $G(A,B)$ be a bipartite graph with $|A| = |B| = n$, where $n$ is sufficiently large(thus, $o(n)/n,o(n^2)/n^2\ll 1$). The edge density of $G$ is $d = \frac{e(A,B)}{n^2}$, where $e(A,B)$ denotes the number of edges between sets $A$ and $B$. Define $a=b\pm c$ to mean $b-c\leq a\leq b+c.$
Definition of regularity:
Let $0 < \varepsilon \ll d < 1$. We say that $G$ is $(\varepsilon, d)$-regular if for any subset $A' \subseteq A$ and $B' \subseteq B$ with $|A'|, |B'| \geq \varepsilon n$, we have
$$
e(A',B') = (d \pm \varepsilon) |A'| |B'|.
$$
Question:
If for any subset $A' \subseteq A$ with $|A'| = n/2+ o(n)$ and $e(A',B) = \frac{dn^2}{2}+ o(n^2)$, and for any subset $B' \subseteq B$ with $|B'| = n/2+ o(n)$ and $e(A,B') = \frac{dn^2}{2}+ o(n^2)$, we have
$$
e(A',B') =(d \pm \varepsilon) |A'| |B'|,
$$
can we conclude that $G$ exhibits some form of regularity (or pseudo-randomness), i.e. $G$ contains a regular subgraph which contains linar numbers of edges with respect to $e(G)$?
In other words, does there exist a constant $c > 0$ (which is independent of $n$, $d$, and $\varepsilon$; for example, $c = 1/4$) and subsetgraph $G'$ with $e(G') \geq c (dn^2)=ce(G)$ such that $G(G')$ is $(f(\varepsilon), d)$-regular, where $f(\varepsilon)$ is some function of $\varepsilon$, possibly $f(\varepsilon) = 4\varepsilon$?
Note that when $G$ is a graph with every vertex has the same degree, the answer is Yes with $c = 1$ and $f(\varepsilon) = \varepsilon$, due to another equivalent definition of regularity (where $A'$, $B'$ can be any subset with $|A'| = |B'| = n/2+o(n)$). However, when $G$ hasn't this property, the answer is unclear for me.

If $n/2$ or $dn^2/2$ aren't integers then the proposition is vacuously true, so it can't imply regularity

@DanielWeber We can think two values are equal if their difference is sufficient small in this type of question

Do you really want the average degree to be much less than 1?  Or is $d$ intended to be a density rather than a degree?

@BrendanMcKay yes, Sorry for mistake, it should be density. I edit it now

@tomjerry please formulate unambiguously
